# Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link on react/next.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

Is it possible using only CSS to make smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link in react component?

```
...
render(
    <a href="#smooth-link">Link To There</a>
    ....
    <div id="smooth-link">
        ....
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's this:

```
/**
 * Smooth scrolling inside an element
 */
#my-element {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/**
 * Smooth scrolling on the whole document
 */
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

[Source](https://gomakethings.com/smooth-scrolling-links-with-only-css/)

But I feel like JS does a better job:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    });
});
```

So you could give that a try: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: Wow. It works well. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 6):

I was using `tailwindcss` but it will work without tailwindcss too.
You just need to add `scroll-behavior:smooth` for `html` tag.
Go to your `.css` file which is global in your project.
Add this line at the top.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: sometimes you have to put  !important; like this
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}

Answer (score 1):

You have to add click listener on anchor tag inside of `<Link>` tag:

```
 <Link href="#about">
     <a className="nav-item" onClick={scrollHandle} id="about-">About Us</a>
 </Link>
```

scrollHandler:-

```
 const scrollHandle = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let id = e.target.id;
  let position = document.getElementById(id.slice(0, id.length - 1)); //removing extra last - (dash)
  window.location.href = "#" + id.slice(0, id.length - 1); // changing the url
  position && position.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" }) //scrolling the page
 }
```